# Си и ряд Тейлора

Tags: c, алгоритм, математика

Задача состоит в том, чтобы высчитать выражения (1 + х)^1/3 для |x| < 1 рядом Тейлора. Я нашел [формулу](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/BinomialSeries/Inline13.gif) и составил алгоритм вот такой

```
fStep = 0.01;
fEps = 0.001;
printf("ok\n");
scanf("%f %f/n", &fX); 
float fTotal = 1.0;
float fNext = 1.0 + ((1.0 / 3.0) * fX);
float fSum = 0;
for (float i = 1.0; fNext - fTotal >= fEps; i++) {
    fTotal = fNext;
    fNext = fNext * ((1.0 / 3.0) - i) * fX / (i+1.0);
    fSum += fTotal;
    }
```

он работает неправильно. Подскажите, где я ошибся.

Comment: "он некорректно работает на отрицательных числах и дает неправильный результат на положительных." - это разные вещи?

Comment: "он работает неправильно" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: После моих исправлений работает правильно, но автора вопроса не видно.

Comment: Элементарно для отрицательных чисел всегда давало 1, потому что не было абсолютного значения в условии.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka abs работает с интами

Comment: abs необходим в численных методах. Работает с действительными числами.

Comment: @GovardMoh работает?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka нет

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka числа неправмльные

Comment: Какой был ввод и какой вывод?

Comment: У меня, например, все числа равны тем, которые получаются на калькуляторе.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka 0.49   ---->  0.9791

Comment: 0.49 дает 1.14155. Проверьте код, такой ли он, как у меня.

Comment: Выделено в отдельную функцию
double tailor(double fX)
{
 double fEps = 0.001;

 double fNext =(1.0 / 3.0) * fX;
 double fSum = 1.0 ;
 for (int i = 1; abs(fNext) >= fEps; i++) {
  fSum += fNext;        

  fNext = fNext * (1-3*i)* fX / (3*(i+1));//1/3-i=(1-3i)/3

 }
 return fSum;
}

Comment: @  HasmikGaryaka ой, извините, все правильно)

Comment: @ HasmikGaryaka но формула fNext = fNext * ((1.0 / 3.0) - i) * fX / (i+1.0);
    тоже прошла тесты

Comment: так читабельнее и быстрее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что бросается в глаза - fNext должен быть очередным членом ряда. Но вы в начале присвоили ему сумму двух первых членов ряда. Можно было бы так

```
float fNext =(1.0 / 3.0) * fX;
float fSum = 1.0 ;
```

А в цикле

```
    for (int i = 1; abs(fNext) >= fEps; i++) {
        fSum += fNext;        

        fNext = fNext * (1-3*i)* fX / (3*(i+1));//1/3-i=(1-3i)/3

   }
```

i целое не испортит вычислений.